# Javascript not recognizing reserved character generated by oracle rowid

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, oracle

I am using oracle rowid as reference to update row selected.
It run smoothly for several months till recently there is some problem
Script as below.

```
update(rowid, value){
$.ajax({
   url: action.php,
   dataType: "json",
   data: {
   value : value,
   ROWID : rowid
   },
  success: function(data){
  //update whatever
    }
   });
}
```

in action.php is just a update script of db table

```
update table set column = '".$_get['value']."' where rowid = '".$_get['ROWID']."'
```

The problem starts when this rowid value input into the script  AAAay1AAEAABw6jAA/
Javascript cannot accept the / or + character which is generated by oracle rowid.

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Tue, 26 Nov 2013 00:13:48 UTC


Message: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #AAAay1AAEAABw6jAA/
Line: 4680
Char: 2
Code: 0
URI: http://192.168.2.2/project/include/js/jquery-1.8.3.js
```

Is not possible to change oracle rowid since I cannot control rowid value.
is not possible for me to do replace string of the value such that javascript read the character ie. from \ to \ If i replace it the rowid value will become AAAay1AAEAABw6jAA// which doesn't work either.

How can I escape from javascript reserve character?

Comment: looks like `#AAAay1AAEAABw6jAA/` is a string literal this has to be enclosed in `''` like `'#AAAay1AAEAABw6jAA/'`

Comment: meaning? can you show me an example?

Comment: You spelled column as `colunm` - is that just a typo in your question?

Comment: can you share the code which is passing the value `#AAAay1AAEAABw6jAA/` to javascript

Comment: matt is my typo sorry

Comment: Arun, update(rowid, value){...} that is a javascript fucntion

Comment: hmm why is there a drop in reputation? any reason?

Comment: You may want to include some more code around the line `update table set column = '".$_get['value']."' where rowid = '".$_get['ROWID']."'`. If this is a problem with escaping characters, then we need to see it in a larger context.

Comment: Matt the problem does not occurred in the update but on the javascript.

Comment: +1 because you made me laugh with "recon-gizing"..... :)

Answer (score 0):

How about using encodeURIComponent and decodeURIComponent

```
var x = "#AAAay1AAEAABw6jAA/";            
var txt=encodeURIComponent(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   data: {
   value : value, // replace "value :" with "value:"
   ROWID : rowid  // replace "ROWID :" with "ROWID:"
   },
```

Because of the spaces before the colons, it is interpreting the "value" and "ROWID" on the left side of the colon as variables, rather than symbols. Just delete the spaces before the colons.